# Queuing up async code to execute sequentially

Tags: c#, async-await

At any time, I can receive a method call that will require a long-running operation to satisfy.

There are several of these methods. Because they share a resource, it's important that they don't run concurrently - each should run in sequence.

Normally, I'd simply make the calls in sequence:

```
var result1 = await Foo1Async();
var result2 = await Foo2Async();
```

However, in this case, the method calls to me are asynchronous:

```
void Bar1()
{
    var result = await Foo1Async();
    // ...
}

void Bar2()
{
    var result = await Foo2Async();
    // ...
}
```

I think I need to use `Task.ContinueWith`, and have come up with this:

```
readonly object syncLock = new Object();

private Task currentOperationTask = TaskUtilities.CompletedTask;
public Task<TResult> EnqueueOperation<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> continuationFunction)
{
    lock (this.syncLock)
    {
        var operation = this.currentOperationTask.ContinueWith(predecessor => continuationFunction()).Unwrap();
        this.currentOperationTask = operation;
        return operation;
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
void Bar1()
{
    var result = await EnqueueOperation(() => Foo1Async());
    // ...
}

void Bar2()
{
    var result = await EnqueueOperation(() => Foo2Async());
    // ...
}
```

Is this the right way to approach this problem? Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of?

Comment: I don't see any problem with that, but I suppose you could lose the `() =>` if you change your signature to `(Task<TResult> continuationFunction)`.

Comment: @YoryeNathan That wouldn't work, it would mean each async method would start executing immediately, the question is about how to avoid that.

Comment: BTW, if your code really looks like this, you can also just write `await EnqueueOperation(Foo1Async);` (without the lambda).

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work fine, I think this is a reasonable way to solve the problem.

A simpler approach to do this would be to use [`AsyncLock` from Nito AsyncEx](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncLock):

```
private readonly AsyncLock asyncLock = new AsyncLock();

public async Task<TResult> EnqueueOperation<TResult>(
    Func<Task<TResult>> continuationFunction)
{
    using (await asyncLock.LockAsync())
    {
        return await continuationFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this also wait for tasks unrelated to `EnqueueOperation` calls?

Comment: @YoryeNathan No, it won't. But if you call `EnqueueOperation()` from the UI thread, it will invoke `continuationFunction` there too, which may not be what you want.